# RxJava Thread switching

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-binding

```
RxBottomNavigationView.itemSelections(sections).map(menuItem -> menuItem.getTitle().toString())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).map(this::insertCategoryHeadersForSection)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .compose(bindToLifecycle()).subscribe(itemInfos -> dishRecyclerAdapter.animateTo(itemInfos));
```

The code above throws this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.
at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:111)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean io.reactivex.internal.fuseable.SimpleQueue.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

I am trying to get the itemSelections event from a BottomNavigationView, then map the item to its title (on the main thread), then run a long operation on a background thread, then receive the output of that operation on the main thread again. Help please. thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have a source that violates the `Observable` protocol by not calling `onSubscribe`. My suspect is `RxBottomNavigationView.itemSelections(sections)` but to be sure, please use the [protocol validator debug support](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#protocol-validation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into a [bug in RxBinding2](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/pull/392) that is fixed in the repo but not yet released. The reason for it is that by using `subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())` you don't move the computation into the background but make the `RxBottomNavigationView.itemSelections(sections)` happen on the background thread which is forbidden and crashes your stream (and app).

You should do this instead:

```
RxBottomNavigationView.itemSelections(sections)
.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())      // <------------------------
.map(menuItem -> menuItem.getTitle().toString())  // main thread
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())              // <------------------------
.map(this::insertCategoryHeadersForSection)       // background
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())        // <------------------------
.compose(bindToLifecycle())
.subscribe(itemInfos ->                           // main
    dishRecyclerAdapter.animateTo(itemInfos));
```